# Apply existing MST file to new MSI package

Tags: windows-installer, orca

I have an "app.msi" file built with Visual Studio 2010 deployment project and "empty.mst" transform created based on "empty.msi" template. When I try to apply "empty.mst" to "app.msi" using Orca, I get following error: "The specified transform could not be applied".

I need to modify "app.msi" so that "empty.mst" transform file can be applied to it, but I can't figure out what exactly is responsible for msi - mst correlation in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Transforms (.mst files) have validation bits in them that can limit the products (.msi files) the transform may apply to. Currently transforms can validate the `UpgradeCode`, `ProductCode`, `ProductVersion` and `ProductLanguage` of the target product. I have not checked, but it is likely that `empty.mst` validates one or more of those values of the `empty.msi` and thus is not generally applicable.

You might just create a transform of your own .msi.

Answer (score 2):

It occured that problem was related to language/localization settings - .msi file had different Code Page value than .mst transform. After changing both to 1252 (English), transform was applied without problems.